# CakePHP show project_id as name

Tags: php, cakephp

My DB structure is quite simple: Projects has many Keywords.

In my `Keywords/index.ctp` I have a `<Table>` which shows all `keywords` and displays their `project_id`. Instead of the ID I want to display the `name` of the `projects`.

Is there a simple code-line for it?

Example:

```
keyword name | project 
Foo           1
bar           1
ipsum         2
```

to

```
keyword name | project 
Foo           DaFoo
bar           DaFoo
ipsum         MoreFoo
```

Comment: you need to create model relationship between them , i.e Keyword belongs to projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have the `belongsTo` relation defined in Keyword model then you can access the Project data like this:

```
$keyword['Project']['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP Associations for more info please visit: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

```
<?php 
class Keyword extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Keyword';

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Project' => array(
            'className' => 'Project',
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
}

class Project extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Project';

     var $hasMany = array(
        'Keyword' => array(
            'className' => 'Keyword',
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );

}
```

?>

and use in .ctp file as below

```
<?php 
$keywords['Project']['name'];
?>
```

Comment: Please let me know if any trubble in above code. glad to help you :)

Comment: definitely will do sir ;)