# CakePHP access the table in hasMany

Tags: php, cakephp, associations

I have a problem based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893084/cakephp-show-project-id-as-name) question.

Same DB: Project has many Keywords - Keyword belongs to Project
To access the `Project Table` in `Keywords/index.ctp` easily use `$keyword['Project']['id']`;

But conversely it seems a bit more difficult. Here a bit code:

```
public function view($id = null) 
{
    if (!$id) 
    {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid project'));
    }
    $this->paginate['Project']['conditions'] = array('Project.id' => $id);
    $this->set('projects', $this->paginate());

    $this->set('project', $project);
}
```

in `Projects/view` I try to access the Keywords table like that: `$project['Keyword']['id']` what I might expected that this isn't working.

Comment: You want all the keywords attached to a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
public function view($id = null) 
{
    if (!$id) 
    {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid project'));
    }
    $this->Project->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array('Keyword' => array('className' => 'Keyword',
                                                       'foreignKey' => 'project_id')
                                    )), false);
    $this->paginate['conditions'] = array('Project.id' => $id);
    $this->paginate['recursive'] = '2';
    $this->set('projects', $this->paginate('Project'));

    $this->set('project', $project);
}
```